# How can .NET app run with 32bit and 64bit Office?

Tags: .net, ms-office, 32bit-64bit, oledbconnection

I have a Windows 64bit system, and a C# app that uses an OleDbConnection to read Excel data via the 32bit version of AccessDatabaseEngine.exe COMponents since I have Office 32bit installed (as recommended by MSFT), and the 64bit version of AccessDatabaseEngine would not work with 32bit Office.

In order to get my C# app to work, I had to set "Prefer 32-bit" in the project build settings. This sets the compiler /platform anycpu32bitpreferred flag. There is no "preferred" about this on Intel platforms.

So everything runs fine. On my machine. Not on my boss' 64bit machine where he installed 64 bit Office.

I cannot find any app.config option to force 64bit. Is there one? Is it theoretically possible in the .NET load sequence that there could be one?

MSFT did not think this through. I should somehow be able to build an app that can work with both 32 and 64 bit versions of Office. Can I somehow using OleDbConnection?

I know about the CorFlags.exe /32bitpref- flag but this requires maintaining two versions of the binary.

Any ideas? Fixes? App.Config options?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download [the 64 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) of the ODBC driver (it says access but it does excel driver too).

You will likely get a error saying you can not have both 32 bit and 64 bit installed at the same time, to get around this you must [use the /passive flag](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/)

> To install the Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider 32-bit on a machine running Office 2010 64-bit:
>
> - AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive
>
> To install the Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider 64-bit on a machine running Office 2010 32-bit:
>
> - AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /passive

Comment: See here for the famous "/passive" trick to install both 32-bit *and* 64-bit drivers on the same machine: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

Comment: Oh WOW! I wish I knew that a year ago when I was trying to figure out how to get 32 bit with 64 bit office. Thanks, I have updated my answer with details from that website.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I did not get any notificaitons. If I add the 64-bit driver will it talk to a 32 bit version of Office? Else this does not help. Thanks, Dave

Comment: I installed the 64-bit package with the /passive option, and this seems to allow my system to no longer need the "Prefer 32-bit" option for my apps compiled as CPU ANY to talk with 32 bit Excel. Waiting for feedback from my boss and if Ok then this was the answer. Thanks, Dave

Comment: Ok, works great, thanks! Why does MSFT give the dire warning from the install without /passive??? They should just say install the other or use /passive if you must! Btw, this would not have worked w/o /passive as I needed a 64-bit (ANY) app to interface w/ 32-bit Office one machine and with 64-bit on another, where both machines were 64-bit.

Comment: Actually, though the application works, I'm having issues with the Office apps. Excel and Word "configure" themselves every time they start, and Outlook will no longer create new folders claiming "Outlook cannot read the registry information.". I have done an Office Repair and that did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: I uninstalled the x64 AccessDatabaseEngine, then Word configured itself once, and from then on Word and Excel would start normal rather than configure themselves each time. Then add the x64 AccessDatabaseEngine back in and got the configuring each time behaviour back. This sort of works but I have to be able to add new folders to Outlook and don't want the delay every time WOrd or Excel starts. So sorry, but unmarking as the answer unless I can also get rid of the collateral damage.

Comment: This also keeps me from signing into MSDN. Says "something went wrong"...aftr uninstalling, I get in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ODBC to talk to Excel instead of the AccessDatabaseEngine COM object.  This would skip the 32/64 bit issue.

Comment: Thanks, but don't want to use ODBC.